# Android application is not working properly when enable proguard

Tags: android, android-widget, xmpp, proguard, socketexception

I am developing an application. It works fine without `proguard` but when I enable `proguard` it doesn't work properly.

XMPP port cannot be opened and it throws **socket exception**.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because proguard obfuscates your code and if you use some external libraries you should make the obfuscation rules accordingly... you should check this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

**EDIT:**

The rules I have in my project are:

```
-libraryjars library_used.jar
```

And also if you get some class not found exception then you might want to remove that class from the obfuscation process like this:

```
-keep public class org.package.YourClassHere
```

Note that I am not 100% if this is the best way to do this but at least it works :)

Comment: Hi Cata, Thanks. I have read that but i dont know how to ignore libs from obfuscation.Plase explain how to do that.some sample proguard commands.

Comment: I don't have the project with me now.. latter when I will have it I will post here what I did before to fix this

Comment: Updated my post, please try the following :)

Comment: Hi Cata, I am almost done with your guidelines but when invoking some server call from my application it throws exception. That is a method named open() available in jar file. The application throws exception when try to call the menthod open().Is there any suggestions from your side.